# c++ vector inside struct inside class stays unmodified

Tags: c++, class, vector

Thanks a lot for taking time to answer my question!
Sorry for my bad C++ tbh i m more used to embedded C, for all my university school projects.

Ok hereby i ll post the entire piece of code, which has now been modified thanks to your comments.

some answers:

- the problem is when i don't use "strcmp" my compiler gives me the following warning: "Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
  comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress] tafel.cpp"
  and it does indeed behave in quit a strange manner it doesn't stop the while loop when I type "end"
  what i originally type(d): see code
- I tried to correct everything what has been told. but I do need the tafelnummer static variable inside your tafel::nieuwebestelling() method. Because I am making a "restaurant-program". And that variables also indicates the tablenumber. So for instance if table 1 orders 5 beers. The content of the vector will be 5x beer. And the index (tafelnummer) would be 1. I *think* this is a good way to start for the program.

the problem:

---> the problem is still the same: first i go to the function "nieuwe bestelling", wich allows me to fill the vector. Afterwards I print the vector with the function toevoegen but it s still empty

the code:

/*
 * tafel.cpp
 *  Created on: 18 Jul 2014
 *      Author: alex
 */

```
#include "../tafel.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

tafel::tafel() {
    //constr
}

void tafel::nieuwebestelling()
{
        std::string besteld;
        static int tafelnummer=1;

        while(besteld!= "end")
        {
            std::cout<<"bestelling: ";
            std::getline (std::cin,besteld);
            bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten.push_back(besteld);
        }
        std::cout<<"---------------------------"<<std::endl;
}
void tafel::toevoegen()
{

    int tafelnummer=1;
    std::cout<<"----------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"gewijzigd"<<std::endl;

    for(unsigned int i =0; i< bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"i";
        std::cout<< bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"eind"<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>tafelnummer; //This is just here so i can clearly see, the point where everything should be printed
}
```

.

```
/*
 * tafel.h
 *
 *  Created on: 18 Jul 2014
 *      Author: alex
 */

#ifndef TAFEL_H_
#define TAFEL_H_

#define tafels 10

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


class tafel {
public:
    static int i;
    struct bestelling  //elke tafel heeft een struct waarin alle gerechten enzo in staan. ide struct = ide tafel
    {
        std::vector<std::string>gerechten;
    }bestellingen[tafels];

    tafel();
    void nieuwebestelling();
    void toevoegen();
};


#endif /* TAFEL_H_ */
```

Comment: As a side note: `while((strcmp(besteld,"end"))!=0)` is UB since `besteled` is not assigned with anything.

Comment: `besteld` can store 5 characters. Yet you request up to 20 characters in `cin.getline(besteld, 20)`

Comment: Use a `std::string` instead of the character array. It's safer and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it's not working (aside from the obvious issues pointed in the comments), but on my side it works. Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const int tafels=16;

class tafel
{
public:
    struct bestelling 
    {
        vector<string>gerechten;  // <-- the vector
    }bestellingen[tafels];

    tafel(){};
    void nieuwebestelling();
    void toevoegen();
    virtual ~tafel(){};
};

void tafel::nieuwebestelling()
{
    char besteld[20]={};
    static int tafelnummer=1;

    while((strcmp(besteld,"end"))!=0)
    {
        cout<<"YOUR ORDER: ";
        cin.getline(besteld,20);
        bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten.push_back(besteld);
    }
    cout<<"---------------------------"<<endl;
}

void tafel::toevoegen()
{

    int tafelnummer=1;
    cout<<"THE VECTOR:"<<endl;   //contains what you ordered previously.

    //DOESN T GET PRINTED    
    for(unsigned int i =0; i< bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<< bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout <<"end"<<endl<<endl; //is printed
}

int main()
{
    tafel foo;
    foo.nieuwebestelling(); 
    foo. toevoegen(); // it prints the vector
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to post a *compilable* sample code in your question.

For example, in the code you posted, you have a raw C-like array of `struct bestelling`, which is a data member of the `tafel` class: `bestellingen[tafels]`. But where is `tafels` defined?

Moreover, your code is of low quality, since it has a mix of C-isms and C++ stuff.

For example, why do you mix `std::vector` and raw C-like arrays?

Unless there is a strong reason to not doing so, you should always consider **`std::vector`** as your default container in C++, instead of raw C-like arrays.

Moreover, you used `strcmp()` to compare strings, and raw `char` arrays to store strings. That's bad C++. Just consider using the `std::string` class, which properly overloads `operator==` for comparisons, and is much better than raw C-like `char` arrays.

In other words, I'd suggest you to port your code from this mix of "old C-style" and C++, to a pure C++ modern code, using `std::vector` and `std::string`.
The `std::vector` automatically grows if you call its `push_back()` method, so you don't need the `tafelnummer` `static` variable inside your `tafel::nieuwebestelling()` method. Just use `std::vector` and its `push_back()` method to add new stuff to the vector.

Moreover, in header files, use fully qualified names with the `std::` prefix, e.g. `std::vector` (not `vector`). In fact, `using namespace std;` in header files will pollute the global namespace, and it's a bad practice.